# my app killed by android system when it running in background

Tags: android

I want to create application that can play a streaming music . When I press home my app can running in background but when I open another application that use more memory my app will stop and killed by android system . Anyone have another idea to run my music player app in background?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement a foreground service:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a
>   notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing"
>   heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless
>   the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

Example:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: If this is really needed, why aren't messengers like WhatsApp being killed?

Comment: @mgutt, this duplicate SO question has more comprehensive answers: [How can we prevent a Service from being killed by OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696861)

Answer (score 3):

Look the activity lifecycle :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

I think you must do a service.

Comment: a foreground service is actually what they want, the same way the native player works where you have an ongoing notification see @devconsole's answer