# Prevent Android killing service

Tags: android, service

I need to make a service for an Android OS that we have built. I want to make the system not kill this service.

This is an Android OS for a very specific purpose, to be used on tablets in prisons. We want to be able to update the apps without using the playstore in the background. I have got it to update, I was just wondering whether it is possible to prevent the system killing the service.

Also this service is set to boot if the OS kills the app will that prevent the boot receive.

Comment: I hope this prisons are not in my area... :) Your service will be killed by the system in certain conditions, you can not prevent this. You can only make it less possible. Read the [best practices](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Android Service From Being Killed By OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512809/prevent-android-service-from-being-killed-by-os)