# start application from scratch if killed from task manager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kill-process, taskmanager

I am running an AsyncTask on the login screen for which I am using process dialog.

The problem is if I kill my application from recent application or from the settings and again launching it from launcher.

```
1.It is starting from the last activity opened.

2. It is starting my assyncTask also due to which my application is crashing because it is not getting View.
```

Question is:- how I can start my application from scratch if it is killed from task Manager.

Comment: why would You do this? Android handles like this for a good reason. I don´t think that it would be good if an app can always restart itself if it gets killed...

Comment: Also (for point 2), You should ask Yourself, why Your app crashs and how to avoid this...

Comment: Other application if I kill from task manager , they are staring from scratch. how they achieve this. please help

Comment: For this You have to use a Service and use startForeground(). Here are some examples: http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/  and:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696861/how-can-we-prevent-service-from-killing-by-os-in-android