# Resume music using Service when we Resume the application

Tags: android, service

I'm developing an application, which plays music in the background by using service.
Music stops when we hit back app will be paused and but, music is not resuming when I get back to the application.

```
public class backService extends Service implements ComponentCallbacks2 {
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public Boolean musicSwitch;

 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
 if (mp != null){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
  }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    musicSwitch = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("music", true);
    if(musicSwitch){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.all);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
}



@Override
public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
    if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.pause();
        }
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
    }
```

I want the application to resume music when we get back to the application, I have tried using `onResume` method, but there is no `onResume` method in services.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to create foreground service to prevent it from killing by OS
[How can we prevent a Service from being killed by OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696861/how-can-we-prevent-a-service-from-being-killed-by-os)

2) You can bind service (`bindService(serviceIntent)`) and use `Binder` interface
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
// Random number generator
private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return LocalService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber() {
  return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
LocalService mService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unbindService(mConnection);
    mBound = false;
}

/** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
  * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (mBound) {
        // Call a method from the LocalService.
        // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
        // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
        int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
        Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
}
}
```

3) Then, in your activity `onResume` you can call method from your Binder to control music